# Why do razor pages return a Task<IActionResult> rather than an IActionResult?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Razor Pages are introduced in Asp.Net Core 2.0 as way to create page centric web applications and in many ways are easier to write than the typical controller, view, model approach.  I've been studying the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ and one of the things I find curious is that the action methods in the code-behind file utilize the `async` `await` pattern and therefore return a `Task<IActionResult>` rather than returning `IActionResult` the way a standard Asp.Net Core action method does. I find it odd because this approach is more complex than the approach used by a standard Asp.Net Core action method and that seems to run contrary to the design simplicity of Razor Pages.

Modified example from that source:

```
  public class ContactModel : PageModel {

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {
        //Other code omitted

        return Page();
    }
  }
```

For comparision, in a regular Asp.Net Core Controller this same code would look like:

```
 public class Contact: Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult OnPost() {           
        //Other code omitted

        return View();
    }
 }
```

Why does the Razor Pages action method use the `async` `await` pattern returning a `Task<IActionResult>` rather than using the simpler approach that the regular Asp.Net core action methods uses by simply returning a `IActionResult`?  Why was such a design choice made?

Comment: Because you are executing and awaiting an asynchronous call in your action so the return type must be `Task`. You also want to return something from your method so now you have to use the generic version of `Task<T>`.  (*assuming the compiler would allow it*) If you did not return Task with your async/await then your call would not be awaitable and no result could be returned to the caller. I think it would be better for you to read about how async/await works. [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Igor, thanks.  I get that, and I understand the async await pattern.  But I don't understand why this pattern was chosen given that it's a more complex approach than a standard mvc action method uses.  I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: That code was just part of their example which isn't particularly relevant to my question.  I have updated my question to use a modified version of their example to omit the code so it doesn't confuse anyone else.

Comment: @Igor - I updated my question further to make it more clear and removed code from the example that was extraneous.

Comment: I believe the example you reference is asynchronous but that is not stopping you from creating an action that is synchronous by just using the same signature as in your 2nd code block (not sure about the HttpPostAttribute though as it looks like its naming convention). You should pick the signature based on if you are making any asynchronous calls or not.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  Given this was the intro documentation to Razor pages it's odd they started with an `async` `await` example if using the approach wasn't necessary, especially given that all action method are inherently asynchronous given they are called downstream of the middleware which uses async await.  But based on your comment I was able to find an example on this page: https://dzone.com/articles/creating-simple-shoutbox-using-aspnet-core-razor-p that confirms that a Razor Page can in fact simply return an IActionResult.  If you put your response as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @RonC: Most action methods need to do I/O (database access and/or web APIs), and thus should default to asynchrony. Synchronous action methods are the exception these days.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks.  I get that but given that the MVC middleware is called via an async await, and that middleware is what's calling the action method, in a sense all action method are running with asynchrony.  So In my mind, whether the action method should use async await just boils down to whether you are making calls from the action method that need to leverage async await.  No?

Comment: Calling via `await` only *allows* asynchrony. Synchronous action methods run synchronously. And yes, your action method should use `async` if (and only if) it needs to use `await` - the point of my comment is that this is the common scenario, and thus it makes sense to have tutorials use `async` action methods.

Comment: Gotcha, I can see that for many post methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the example you reference is asynchronous but that is not stopping you from creating an action that is synchronous by just using the same signature as in your 2nd code block (*not sure about the `HttpPostAttribute` though as it looks like its naming convention*).

```
public IActionResult OnPost() {  /* code here */ }
```